# difference between method and attribute python?

Tags: python

I'm probably using the wrong terminology here, but I'm looking for an explanation on the difference between a function called on an object, i.e. method, and then an attribute of the object itself.

Take the following df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[4, 5, 6, 7],
                   'b':[3, 2, 5, 4]})
```

You can call the `sum()` method/function on df, and you can call the `columns` attribute on df. I may be getting confused between chaining a method vs. calling an attribute using `.`.

```
df.sum()
df.columns
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. You seem to know the difference: a method is a function you call, an attribute is just a value.

Comment: I think `colums` should be `property`. Both `sum` and `columns` are attributes.

Comment: And one of those attributes happens to be a function (which returns a number), and the other happens to be a number.

Answer (score 0):

They're the same. Methods are pretty much just attributes that *happen* to be of type `function` or any other runnable type. If you do

```
>>> f = df.sum
```

it'll work perfectly fine. If you then check the type, you'll see

```
>>> type(f)
<type 'instancemethod'>
```

or something similar along those lines. You can call any object of that type as a function, which is why you can do `df.sum()`: first it's finding the attribute of `df` that happens to be a function, and then it's calling it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't "call" the `df.columns` part of a DataFrame. It's a data part of a DataFrame, and you "reference" it. `df.sum()` you can "call", because `sum()` is an executable part of the DataFrame.

The tricky bit (and I'm trying to avoid ambiguous language here) is that a DataFrame *has* both of those kinds of things:  data parts and code parts.  They can both change, be inherited, etc.  But they're really different:  You can't "call" columns, and you (generally) don't reference `sum()`.